# Get subprocess ID of Firefox Flash plugin using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, subprocess, pid

I am using a Selenium Firefox WebDriver from a java app and I need to know the PID of the external plug-ins that the browser uses (or more accurately the PID of a flash player plug-in).
I understand that this is not "easy" to do in java as java do not nativity support access to system information outside the JVM, but maybe any of you know a way to do it with the Firefox/selenium API.

My current workaround is as follows:
- Get my own PID: 
Integer my_pid =Integer.valueOf(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0]);

- Run external program "pslist" (from windows pstools).
- Parse the output and and get your children (with "my_pid" as the reference).

I hate using external programs for trivial tasks. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be that a C# Selenium Firefox test would have access to Windows APIs?  Looking forward to whoever can answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no choice but to use an external program for this.
There is a bug report that was opened to Sun regarding this issue 10 years ago and it is not yet handled.